# Does anything prevent std::optional::value_or() from being conditionally noexcept?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, noexcept, stdoptional

Here's the definition of `value_or()` from the C++17 standard:

> `template <class U> constexpr T value_or(U&& v) const&;`
>
> *Effects: Equivalent to:*
>
> `return bool(*this) ? **this : static_cast<T>(std::forward<U>(v));`
>
> *Remarks: If `is_copy_constructible_v<T> && is_convertible_v<U&&, T>` is `false`, the program is ill-formed.*

(the rvalue overload is similar)

The effect of `value_or` is described as equivalent to `return bool(*this) ? **this : static_cast<T>(std::forward<U>(v));`

`operator bool` is `noexcept`. `operator*` is *not* `noexcept` (even though it doesn't throw, probably because it can still fail with UB if used when the optional does not contain a value). However, we are guaranteed to never try to return the contained value unless we have one.

So couldn't `value_or` be declared `noexcept` given `is_nothrow_copy_constructible<T> && noexcept(static_cast<T>(std::forward<U>(v)))`?

Comment: Conditional noexcept isn't heavily used in the C++ standard might "count" as something that prevents it being used here.

Comment: @Yakk I'd think this answers the posed question, but another one arises immediately: why isn't it widely used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[noexcept](/questions/tagged/noexcept) is used extremely sparingly in the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) standard.  That is about the only barrier.

---

While this answers the question, the next question is "why is it used sparingly".  This is an extra bit of information you might find useful; if this was the core of the answer, I'd include more quotes instead of links.  The paper numbers should outlive the specific hyperlinks I'm using, so there is that.

[N3279](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3279.pdf) is the conclusion of a discussion about noexcept.  Basically, anything with a narrow contract (that can exhibit UB) and isn't a move ctor or dtor is never marked noexcept.

Here are the guidelines:

> Adopted Guidelines
>
> - No library destructor should throw.  They shall use the implicitly supplied (non-throwing) exception specification.
> - Each library function having a wide contract, that the LWG agree cannot throw, should be marked as unconditionally noexcept.
> - If a library swap function, move-constructor, or move-assignment operator is conditionally-wide (i.e. can be proven to not throw by applying the noexcept operator) then it should be marked as conditionally noexcept.  No other function should use a conditional noexcept specification.
> - Library functions designed for compatibility with “C” code (such as the atomics facility), may be marked as unconditionally
>   noexcept.

I wasn't party to the discussion, but basically the idea is that the compiler can *add exceptions* to those methods.

I believe this is called the Lakos rule.  To change it, take it up with the committee.

[N3248](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3248.pdf) is the paper that brought up issues with noexcept.  Mostly it is about testing.

Comment: Relevant guideline to this question is on page 2: only `swap()` and move constructorsassignments in the library are conditionally noexcept.

Comment: At the previous committee meeting, I think that they agreed to make "wrapper types" conditionally `noexcept` based on the operations of the types they wrap. `std::optional` and `std::variant` would be such wrapper types.

Comment: This is a good answer for any "Why is X not noexcept" question

Comment: @morwenn do you have documentation or links to that effect so I can insert a quote with attribution?

Comment: @Morwenn what do you mean by making the type conditionally `noexcept`? Are you referring to any particular operations on them in particular? In c++17, `optional(optional&& rhs)` is already `noexcept` if `is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T>` (and similar for move assignment). `variant` does the same, but it has to hold for all the wrapped types.

Comment: @Yakk The paper I was mentioning was [P0884 - Extending the `noexcept` Policy](https://wg21.link/P0884], which is actually rather terse. The paper cites `std::atomic` and the proposed `std::function_ref` as examples of wrapping types. I just checked the meeting minutes (non public) and the question was raised about `std::optional` and `std::variant` but the actual answer was that the aim of the paper was to broaden the conditional `noexcept` policy not to make firm decisions, so no definite answer for those types. Apparently the committee was strongly for accepting this paper.

Comment: @knatten Just rechecked the paper again and it actually only proposes conditional `noexcept` for the default constructor, copy constructor and copy assignment operator of wrapper types, so unlike what I thought there is no way it affects `value_or`, sorry :/